# Why subclass or child class cannot be public, private and protected in java?

Tags: java, oop

In java when we inherit a public superclass then why we can't make the subclass public.

```
public class Parent {
    int value;
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Hello Parent!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent t = new Child();

    }
}
public class Child extends Parent{ // error here
    int val;
}
```

**// showing error if I use public, private or protected with Child class.**

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the full error?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem.  https://replit.com/@robertwharvey/DisfiguredGeneralJavascript#Parent.java

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think you inadvertently solved the issue by moving the class into its own file Child.java.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, it looks like you are defining both classes in same file.

When you are defining multiple classes in same file , then only one class will be `public` & you save your file with that class name (e.g. `Parent.java` in your case.).

If you want to define your `Child` class as `public`, then it is totally allowed, but create new file & define `Child` class there & save it with `Child.java`.

Alternatively, you can use `Child` & `Parent` classes within same file but remove `public` access modifier from `Child` so that compiler won't complain.